# Prove that the number degree $3$ vertices is less than half of the total number of vertices in a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

How do I prove the following:

$$|\{v\in V : \deg(v)\geq 3\}|<\frac{|V|}{2}$$ is true for all trees $T$.

I don‘t how to approach this exercise. Does anyone have a hint perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you know about trees? Have you tried thinking about it for some specific small values of $n$ (the number of vertices in the tree)?

Comment: Reasoning from the contrary, use the handshake theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be the number of nodes with degree at least $3$ and $n=|V|$.
The handshake lemma gives us
$2n-2=\sum_{v\in V} \deg(v)=\sum_{v\in V, \deg(v)\leq 2} \deg(v)+\sum_{v\in V, \deg(v)\geq 3} \deg(v)\geq 3k+n-k$.
This implies
$\Rightarrow 2k+n\leq 2n-2$
$\Rightarrow 2k\leq n-2$
$\Rightarrow k\leq \frac{n}{2}-1<\frac{n}{2}$